# Line plot producing plot that does not correspond chronologically

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im getting line plot which starts with months in alphabetical ordered. can someone help me get it chronologically?

```
test<- structure(list(Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"
), a = c(11, 10, 9, 8, 4, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Month, y=a, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color="red")+
  geom_point()

# keep getting months arranged alphabetically

# tried Month= month(decision_date, abbr=FALSE

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(decision_date, abbr=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

A first cut would be to assign `Month` as a `factor`, where we can control the order:

```r
test$Month <- factor(test$Month, c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                   "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
# or more succinctly (thanks @JonSpring)
test$Month <- factor(test$Month, month.abb)
```

[image: corrected plot]

(The use of `month.abb` works because they happen to be exactly what you showed in your sample data.)

Further techniques might be to use actual dates instead of arbitrary strings. Realize that while they are "obviously" month abbreviations to your eyes, to R they are merely strings. I suggest if your data is really date-centric, then you should be using `Date`-class objects, not strings, to define your timeline. Even with a `Date` in a variable looking like `2019-07-15`, you can control how it appears on the axis with `ggplot` options fairly easily (different question, and it's been asked-and-answered numerous times on SO).

---

Here's an example of converting to `Date` instead of keeping them as strings:

```r
# starting with your original data
test$Month <- as.Date(paste0("2019-", test$Month, "-01"),
                      format = "%Y-%b-%d")
test
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Month          a
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2019-01-01    11
# 2 2019-02-01    10
# 3 2019-03-01     9
# 4 2019-04-01     8
# 5 2019-05-01     4
# 6 2019-07-01     8
```

Your plot still works as-is, so `ggplot2` is actually defaulting to showing just month-abbreviations here (exactly what you wanted). (I'm assuming the year and day-of-month here ... if you don't care and the analysis/display does not depend on year, then this is fine. If the years do matter elsewhere, you should not just copy this code verbatim. Caveat emptor :-)

Comment: Or use the built-in constant: `months_order <- factor(test$Month, month.abb)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very helpful. Have a nice day my friend.